# How to have have for loop in front of another?

Tags: python

Lets say you're cycling through a string like "hello" and need a nested for loop.

So you say something like:

```
for i in str:
    for j in str:
```

But you want the j loop to start one position in front of the i loop.

So the i loop will start at "h" and the j loop will start at "e"

I thought it would be something like:

```
for i in str:
    j = i + 1
    for j in str:

Error:cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: you try do `j = "h" + 1` so you get error.

Comment: you need to enumerate an integer range not characters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slice the string where you want to start off with, now `j` starts at `'e'` and `i` starts at `h`

```
x = 'hello'

for i in x:
    for j in x[1:]:
        print(i,j)
```

Comment: it doesn't work as  OP expects. `j` always starts at `e` but it have first start at `e`, later at first `l`, later at second `l`, etc.

Comment: @furas eh OP was very unclear, wait where does it says he wants the inner loop the be advanced o.o

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with slices.

```
for i, char in enumerate(s, 1):
    for other_char in s[i:]:
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a `range`:

```
my_string = "hello"

for i in range(len(my_string)):
    j = i - 1 # i-1 is the index before, i+1 would be the position after
```